# trying to remove css grid right margin

Tags: css

I have made a div and assigned display grid to it everything is fine but the problem is there is a margin I don't know if its a code that i wrote wrong or sthg else .. i tried to use `margin : 0 auto;` but didn't work it made it worse actually xD. i  also checked if the container has margin or padding
[Here is what am i talking about :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDK07.png)

```js
$('#owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 30,
    dots: true,
    nav: false,
    rtl: true,
    items: 2,
})
```

```css
.text {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    background: #0b0a0d;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  .text .logo a{
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Zen Dots', cursive;}
  .nav {
    background: #0c70de;
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  
  .text .logo a{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none
  }
  .nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    /* width: 50%; */
    /* margin-left: auto; */
  }
  ul li{
    padding: 20px;
    list-style: none
  }
  ul li a{
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Changa', sans-serif;
  }
  
  .sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%
  }
  .contain {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.item {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
}


/* slider */ 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,400');
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: thin;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
padding: 0;
  
}
body:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: #16151d;

  
}
.movie-card {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 4vh auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  color: white;
  padding: 2vh 3%;
}
.movie-card:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(40,40,60,1) 0%,rgba(40,0,60,0) 90%);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  will-change: transform;
  z-index: 0;
}
i {
  font-size: .7em;
  color: #ff5b84;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 170%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 80px;
  color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
}
.watch {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  margin: 20px 0px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  transition: all .2s;
}
button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
button:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: .8em;
  width: 60%;
  height: 35%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
/*     background: none; */
  }
  .movie-card {
    width: 75%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  h1 {
  font-size: 120%;
  }
  p {
    display: none;
/*     overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%; */
  }
  .watch {
    margin: 5% auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .movie-card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.hot {
    background-color: #694ba1;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.hot h3 {
    color: #FFF;
}
h3  {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.anime-list {
    background-color: #222;
}


/*
  AUTO GRID
  Set the minimum item size with `--auto-grid-min-size` and you'll
  get a fully responsive grid with no media queries.
*/
.auto-grid {
    --auto-grid-min-size: 16rem;
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--auto-grid-min-size), 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1rem;
  }
  
  
  /* Presentational styles */
  

  
  .anime-list ul li {
    padding: 5rem 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
  .anime-list {
      align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html dir="rtl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>owl</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Zen+Dots&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Changa:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <!-- * Header START -->

    <div class="text">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">ON ANIME</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">الرئيسية</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">قائمة الانميات</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">افلام الانمي</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        <div class="contain">
            <div id="owl-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images3.alphacoders.com/820/thumb-1920-820754.png&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images3.alphacoders.com/820/thumb-1920-820754.png&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images3.alphacoders.com/820/thumb-1920-820754.png&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images3.alphacoders.com/820/thumb-1920-820754.png&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="contain">
              <div class="postss">
                <div class="hot">
                    <h3>انميات مميزة</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="anime-list">
                    <ul class="auto-grid">
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 1</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 2</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 3</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 4</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 5</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 6</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 7</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 8</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 9</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 10</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 11</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 12</li>
                      </ul>

                </div>
              </div>
          </div>


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to over wright the default of the grid ul

So I added `ul {padding-inline-start: 0px;}` and it seems to be fixed

```js
$('#owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    margin: 30,
    dots: true,
    nav: false,
    rtl: true,
    items: 2,
})
```

```css
ul {padding-inline-start: 0px;}



.text {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    background: #0b0a0d;
    color: #FFF;
  }
  .text .logo a{
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-family: 'Zen Dots', cursive;}
  .nav {
    background: #0c70de;
    color: #FFF;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
  
  .text .logo a{
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none
  }
  .nav ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    /* width: 50%; */
    /* margin-left: auto; */
  }
  ul li{
    padding: 20px;
    list-style: none
  }
  ul li a{
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Changa', sans-serif;
  }
  
  .sticky{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%
  }
  .contain {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
.item {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 300px;
    justify-content: center;
}


/* slider */ 
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,400');
body {
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  font-weight: thin;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
padding: 0;
  
}
body:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 200%;
  height: 200%;
  background-color: #16151d;

  
}
.movie-card {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 4vh auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 2px 3px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  color: white;
  padding: 2vh 3%;
}
.movie-card:after{
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(40,40,60,1) 0%,rgba(40,0,60,0) 90%);
  background-blend-mode: multiply;
  will-change: transform;
  z-index: 0;
}
i {
  font-size: .7em;
  color: #ff5b84;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 170%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  margin-right: 80px;
  color: rgb(210, 210, 210);
}
.watch {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  margin: 20px 0px;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  transition: all .2s;
}
button:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
  color: black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
button:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
p {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
  font-size: .8em;
  width: 60%;
  height: 35%;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  body {
/*     background: none; */
  }
  .movie-card {
    width: 75%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  h1 {
  font-size: 120%;
  }
  p {
    display: none;
/*     overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30%; */
  }
  .watch {
    margin: 5% auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
  .movie-card {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.hot {
    background-color: #694ba1;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
}
.hot h3 {
    color: #FFF;
}
h3  {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
.anime-list {
    background-color: #222;
}


/*
  AUTO GRID
  Set the minimum item size with `--auto-grid-min-size` and you'll
  get a fully responsive grid with no media queries.
*/
.auto-grid {
    --auto-grid-min-size: 16rem;
    
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(var(--auto-grid-min-size), 1fr));
    grid-gap: 1rem;
  }
  
  
  /* Presentational styles */
  

  
  .anime-list ul li {
    padding: 5rem 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
  }
  .anime-list {
      align-items: center;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html dir="rtl">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>owl</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.2.3/animate.min.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Zen+Dots&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Changa:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
         <!-- * Header START -->

    <div class="text">
        <div class="logo">
            <a href="#">ON ANIME</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
        
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">الرئيسية</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">قائمة الانميات</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">افلام الانمي</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        <div class="contain">
            <div id="owl-carousel" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images3.alphacoders.com/820/thumb-1920-820754.png&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images3.alphacoders.com/820/thumb-1920-820754.png&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images3.alphacoders.com/820/thumb-1920-820754.png&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://images3.alphacoders.com/820/thumb-1920-820754.png&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <div class="movie-card" style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);"><h1>The Incredibles 2</h1><span>92 min</span><span>5 <i class="fas fa-star"></i></span><p>Helen is called on to lead a campaign to bring Supers back, while Bob navigates the day-to-day heroics of 'normal' life at home with Violet, Dash and baby Jack-Jack - whose superpowers are about to be discovered.</p><button class="watch">WATCH MOVIE</button></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="contain">
              <div class="postss">
                <div class="hot">
                    <h3>انميات مميزة</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="anime-list">
                    <ul class="auto-grid">
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 1</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 2</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 3</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 4</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 5</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 6</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 7</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 8</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 9</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 10</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 11</li>
                        <li style="background-image: url(&quot;https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/2412138.jpg&quot;);">Item 12</li>
                      </ul>

                </div>
              </div>
          </div>


        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```